# The asymptotic stability if the time derivative of Lyapunov function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

The dynamic equation of motion of the system is 
\begin{align}
\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{l}\sin\theta = 0
\end{align}
We should consider first the total energy function as a Lyapunov function candidate, hence:
\begin{align}
V(\dot{\theta},\theta) 
&= \frac{1}{2} ml^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + mgl(1-\cos\theta) \tag{1}
\end{align}
The Eq.(1) is not positive definite function because $V(\dot{\theta},\theta) = 0$ at $\theta \neq 0$ (i.e. at $\theta = 2n\pi, \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$). If the domain of $\theta$ in $(-2\pi,2\pi)$, then the Eq.(1) is indeed positive definite. The time-derivative of $V(\dot{\theta},\theta)$, hence:
\begin{align}
\dot{V}(\theta,\dot{\theta}) &= \frac{\partial V(\theta,\dot{\theta})}{\partial \dot{\theta}} \frac{\partial \dot{\theta}}{ \partial t} + \frac{\partial V(\theta,\dot{\theta})}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{ \partial t}  \notag \\
&= (ml^2 \dot{\theta}) \ddot{\theta} + (mgl\sin\theta) \dot{\theta}  \notag \\
&= (ml^2 \dot{\theta}) (-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta) + (mgl\sin\theta) \dot{\theta}  \notag \\
&= -mgl \dot{\theta}\sin\theta + mgl\dot{\theta}\sin\theta   \notag \\
&= 0  
\end{align}
Since $\dot{V}(\theta,\dot{\theta}) \leq 0$, the origin is stable. Is it possible to investigate the **asymptotic** stability if $\dot{V}(\theta,\dot{\theta})=0$. As far I as I know, we can use the invariance principle (i.e. LaSalle's theorem), but I can't see how to utilize this theorem in case $\dot{V}(\theta,\dot{\theta})=0$. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Your pendulum equation doesn't include friction. Usually you need some kind of friction for asymptotic stability, like e.g. an extra $+b \dot{\theta}$ in the ODE ($b > 0$ is a constant parameter).

Comment: @SampleTime true but I am asking generally.

Comment: Generally, if $\dot{V}(x) = 0$ means that $V(x)$ is a first integral of your system, so its orbits are level sets of $V$, so for (local) positive definite $V$, the system cannot be asymptotically stable because it cannot "lose" energy.